# Launch executable with custom root directory

Tags: macos, mac, unix, sandbox

How can I launch an executable so it thinks that the root directory is at a custom path, and not at the actual root. I thought it would be possible with sandbox-exec, but I haven't found any ways so far.

Comment: Not sure what the exact mechanics would be on OS X, but the general term that you are looking for is `chroot`. Feed that into your favorite search engine.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about `chroot`. Do you want to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general term on Unix-like operating systems to run a process with a dedicated root directory is `chroot` (short for "change root directory").

The canonical way to do this is something like:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/chroot-dir
$ cp /bin/sh /tmp/chroot-dir/
$ chroot /tmp/chroot-dir /sh
```

Assuming you have execute turned on on /tmp, that would change the root directory such that `/tmp/chroot-dir` becomes the new `/` for that process, then execute `/sh` within the context of that. It is possible that `chroot` will require you to be the root user; in that case, substitute `sudo chroot` for `chroot`. When you exit from the spawned shell, everything will be back to normal.

Since /bin/sh probably needs some libraries, the specific example is likely to fail, but it will be pointing you in the right direction for what else is needed. On Linux, running `ldd /bin/sh` will tell you what additional libraries are required; OS X probably has something similar, if not the same thing. Non-trivial software also often needs configuration files, device nodes and other odds and ends available in its view of the file system.

Consumer-oriented software generally doesn't take very well to being chrooted without significant effort, but server software can often be coaxed into a chroot with relatively little effort, and some even come with documentation on exactly what's needed.